# Flash cs6 and Flash Builder, workflow

Tags: workflow, flash-builder, flash-cs5.5

I wish I could pose more specific questions on this topic, but what I'm really looking for is a bird's eye view - a blog post, something from Adobe, documentation or even a book that outlines an approach, because I've had a tough time finding something comprehensive.

I've primarily been developing in a 2 man team with Flash Pro for years - an artist and developer. I've also worked in larger teams, using the same workflow:

- AS code written as class files using Flash Pro editor, with minimal code on the timeline (only stops and an occasional function call when the timeline hits a certain frame).
- Library assets are linked to AS3 classes where needed
- Assets are placed on the main stage & main timeline, for maximum convenience of the designer.
- Apps are published and built by exporting to swf with Flash Pro
- No source control whatsoever except telling each other if we are going to change the fla.

Our shop is on the verge of bringing in more coders to develop a series of Flash browser games, and I'm thinking it's time to bring this workflow into the current reality. We'll want to have something that suits both artists and coders (minimizing complaints from either camp), as well as git support for source control.

Finally, my questions:

- How are most developers authoring games currently? I've read a popular approach is to create art assets in a fla using Flash pro, link them to classes and export to a SWC. Code is then developed in Flash Builder, where assets are embedded.
- If I take the SWC approach, is all code stripped from the timeline of MovieClip assets?
- I'm aware that Flash Builder has an option to create a 'Flash professional' project which integrates the two and seems ideal, but going back and forth between Builder and Pro seemed to be crash prone. Does anyone use this approach reliably?
- Will CS6 give us any advantages over CS5.5 to make it more developer friendly; ie. code-completion, etc.
- Is there a way to set up workflow so the artist could make changes and then build/run the game from Flash Pro, and the developers could do it from Flash Builder - or would everyone need Flash Builder to run?
- Are there any good 3rd party tools that provide code completion and an all around better development environment then the flash IDE (as an alternative to Flash Builder)?
- Do people see Flash Builder as a 'must have' when working in teams or in general Flash dev?

Thanks for answering any part of these questions, or just simply sharing your experiences, opinions, and personal preferences. Any knowledge will be a big help at this point!

Answer (score 7):

That is a lot of questions for one question. I'll try to somewhat cover the main topic of workflow.

The approach you describe with a pure ActionScript project with swc:s linked in is probably the most common approach (at least when it comes to more complex projects) as you want to separate code from content as much as possible. Usually I work with one artist so we sync up on functional design and then I define how the scene objects should be structured (i.e. a container clip, with XYZ child clips, naming, linkage and everything) to make it fit in with current framework or new supporting code.

You do not want any code in the flash pro timeline whatsoever, you want it all in your ActionScript files. Ideally as a programmer you shouldn't have to go into the flash scene project. However, in reality you probably will. I usually try to keep this to my own placeholder scene so I don't contaminate the production files with test and placeholders. You also really don't want several people editing in the same scene at once. One approach is to split up into several different scene projects. If you make a card game you could have something like this: card.swc, mainScene.swc, opponents.swc. That also allows for some concurrency if you are working with multiple artists.

Keeping the flash pro files in xfl format makes it a bit more source control friendly and you could actually merge two versions of the same scene but it can be a bit complex at times.
I usually solve this by making quick functional placeholder graphics that can later on is replaced by an artist (or render graphics from code).

When it comes to IDE:s, I think the most popular ones are FlashDevelop, Flash Builder and IntelliJ IDEA (With Flash Builder as my personal favourite). Get started with one and try some of the others in due time. Make sure the functions you use all day long are really good. However, if you have only been working with the flash professional environment before anything will be a drastic improvement on productivity.

I for one prioritize searching, refactoring and ease to follow the program flow, which simplifies debugging and getting into other peoples code quickly. But it all really comes down to finding a tool that runs on a frequency you can tune your mind into.

I hope that answered some of your thoughts and questions. Do not hesitate to follow up with more of them.

Comment: Thank you, I know it was a long-winded question... your help is very much appreciated. I'm definitely leaning toward Flash Builder with the swc approach.

Comment: No worries. Just found another IDE that seems worth a look. Free for open source projects and also has a free limited version. Looks awesome from what I've seen so far. Flash Builder has some quirks. Like not being able to resolve missing imports etc. Which this one does with flying colors. http://fdt.powerflasher.com/